# Convert this SQL with count and grouping to linq2SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, count, group-by, aggregate-functions

Can someone convert this query to linq2sql for me? Trying to teach myself linq to see if I want to use it for a small project, and getting hung up on the smallest details...

```
SELECT  
  Warrant.ID, 
  Warrant.MeetingDate, 
  Warrant.MeetingType, 
  Warrant.Notes, 
COUNT(WarrantArticles.ID) AS Cnt
FROM  Warrant INNER JOIN  WarrantArticles ON Warrant.ID = WarrantArticles.WarrantID
   group by   Warrant.ID, Warrant.MeetingDate, Warrant.MeetingType, Warrant.Notes
```

Comment: What does your DataContext look like?

Comment: Not exactly sure how to answer that question: there are just two tables, where the ID in the warrant table is primary key, and it is linked to the warrantArticles table by a field called WarrantID in a one-to-many relationship? This is just a simple test to tryout linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel asked about your ObjectContext because it would be hard to give you a definitive answer without knowing that.

That being said, your query might look something like this

```
var result = from w in context.Warrant select new {w.ID, w.MeetingDate, w.MeetingType, w.Notes, w.Articles.Count};

or

var result = context.Warrant.Select(w=> new new {w.ID, w.MeetingDate, w.MeetingType, w.Notes, w.Articles.Count});
```

Comment: Not exactly the answer, but gave me the missing clue for what I needed - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great tool that will do this for you. The tool is called Linqer (I have no affiliation with it). It will take most SQL statements and convert them to a Linq query. I have used it many times to help me convert more difficult queries.